# How do I know if I should enqueue JS code or just include it in ONE PHP function?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I've read in tons of articles that enqueueing is the way to go...blah blah blah....but does that only apply to when the JS code itself will be repeated across many pages?

For example, I have a bit of JS code that submits payment info to Braintree's servers. Does this need to be enqueued? I only really want to use this code on any page that has the Braintree payment form on it (for now, there is only 1 page that has this form). I could also simply add it to the function that generates the form. Would this be better? I have no experience to know what is good or bad when it comes to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in this case would be to enqueue the js file inside the WP functions.php file. Are the braintree submit pages on their own unique templates? If so you could add something like this to your functions file:

```
function register_scripts() {

if(is_page_template('template-parts/page-braintree.php')):
    wp_register_script( 'braintree-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/braintree.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'braintree-js' );
endif;


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );
```

There is a few assumptions here:

- You have created a page template for the braintree pages, you could use is_page and put in the array of pages it occurs on
- Im assuming you put your js file in a 'js' folder inside your theme and that the js file is called braintree.js

**Why enqueue scripts in functions?**
I use to ask myself this question, it easy enough to manage 2-3 js files on a small project but on larger projects it becomes difficulat to manage the loading (enqueuing) of all of your js files. Putting all of the files inside functions makes it really easy to manage. Want to remove a js file from your project? Just comment it out from your functions file.

Comment: @whotwhotwhot If you let me know the name of the js file, if the file is running on a page template, or the id's of the pages it runs on and your template structure I can update the code.

Comment: How do you feel about this: the page that will have the Braintree form also has another form. It's not a template, it's a page generated by an existing plugin that I am modifying. The plugin is a Q&A plugin and I want to add payment functionality to it. For the best checkout feeling to it, I want to make the "Ask question" page have 1 button that will submit the payment info to Braintree and, if successful, submit the question normally through the plugin. Therefore, I had the idea of maybe only including the Braintree JS code in one section of my website - the Ask Question page.

Comment: I thought this would be safer for the site, but then again that's only my paranoia talking because I really don't know what is considered safe/unsafe when it comes to web development. Do you think your method above will work kind of like a `Class` works in PHP, where other code CANNOT use that class's methods? E.g. will this ensure that no other part of the site uses/loads this JS?

Comment: Using my method the js file will only load when the conditions allow it so it is the safest method. This means that it is not accessible outside of this conditions so people viewing say the home page cant see that script. If you can get the id of the ask a question page let me know and I will update my code.

Comment: I'm running on localhost for now so the page is at localhost/wordpress/index.php/questions/ask. Ok so this gives me another question - what is the point of enqueueing scripts? Is the sole purpose to make sure that you don't reload multiple copies of the same JS code?

Comment: I don't understand why it would be a bad idea to simply add the few lines of JS code into the function that generates my Braintree form. That would utilize your method of using JS within a form because then that JS would only be enlisted when the function is called, no?

Comment: Yes but lets say for example you stop working on the project and another dev comes along, they might not know where the script is being called from and forget about.

Comment: Are you using custom post type's for the page that displays the form? I see the url is index.php/questions/ask

Comment: I totally hear you on that dev-to-dev help that you're talking about in your first comment (this whole project is to extend someone else's plugin), but I guess I don't really intend for someone else to work on this at least for another few years. My question came from the perspective of "Besides code-legibility, is there anything to worry about if I don't enqueue script code and just place it within a function?" And as for the custom post type's - I just started reading all of the code behind this plugin so I wouldn't have an answer to that just yet.